# C++: how to calculate RMSE between 2 vectors

Tags: c++

For example, to calculate the inner product of a vector A, rather than to loop each element in the vector and calculate a sum, we can use  library's inner_product() function:

```
std::inner_product(A.begin(), A.end(), A.begin(), 0.0);
```

I want to know if there exists a similar piece of code available to calculate the root mean squared error (RMSE) between 2 vectors (with the same size, of course) A and B?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The only similar functions are listed [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric). However, you can implement a function your self that does this.

Comment: This is pretty trivial if you notice [`std::inner_product`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product) has an overload accepting two binary operations. Let the first be `std::plus<>()` and the second a lambda taking element subtraction ^ 2, the rest is easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no function specifically for calculating the RMSE. There are, however, functions that can help you do that by providing binary operations, like `std::transform_reduce`.

```
auto squareError = [](T a, T b) {
    auto e = a-b;
    return e*e;
};
auto sum = std::transform_reduce(A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin(), 0, std::plus<>(), squareError);
auto rmse = std::sqrt(sum / A.size());
```

`std::transform_reduce` might not yet be implemented in your compiler's library. In that case, you can use the less descriptive overload of `std::inner_product` (the same way).

Comment: First of all, a.size() will not work, as a is not defined. Perhaps A.size(), which is one of the input vectors. 

Secondly, you are missing a semicolon at the end of the squareError definition.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.
Based on miradulo and Nelfeal's answer, both `std::inner_product()` and `std::transform_reduce()` with proper overheads will do the trick.

overhead 1: `plus<>()`

overhead 2: lambda function

```
auto squaredError = [](auto a, auto b) {
    auto error = a - b;
    return (error * error);
}
```